# Go to `AppStore` with button click

Tags: objective-c

When the user presses on a specific `UIButton` the app should open a song in `Spotify` app, if the app does not exist on the phone, i need it to take the user to the `AppStore` to the `Spotify` app so the user can download it.

Ay idea how i can do so ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do so you will have to :

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:spotifyUrl]])
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:spotifyUrl]];
}
else
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:linkOfSpotifyOnAppstore]]
}
```

Comment: i know this is the way but how do i know what is the link to spotify on appstore ?

Comment: from a google search : https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/spotify-music/id324684580?mt=8

Comment: Instead of using `openURL` to a link in iTunes, you should use `SKStoreProductViewController`.